# Calculating aggregate sums of non-exclusive values in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a Python dictionary, and in my first key-value pair I have a list of varying strings (varying number and varying actual string).

```
my_dict = [{"var1":['a','b'],
           "var2": 34},
          {"var1":['a','c'],
           "var2": 2},
          {"var1":['c','d','e'],
           "var2": 17},
          {"var1":['b','e'],
           "var2": 29},
          {"var1":['a','d','e'],
           "var2": 10},
          {"var1":['b','d'],
           "var2": 21}]
```

I want to work out the average and sum for each of the different values in the `var1` key value pair. So for example, for the value 'a', the sum would be 34 (1st item) + 2 (2nd item) + 10 (5th item) = 46, and for b it would be 34 (1st) + 29 (4th) + 21 (6th) = 74. I'd like a row for each value in a dataframe.

I've tried `Counter` from `collections` but that doesn't fit the bill.

Comment: Show us your non working code if you want us to tell you what went wrong...

Comment: Create two result dictionaries, iterate through your dictionaries. For each dict iterate through the list of "var1". For each list item use it as key to the result dictionaries and add up the value of "var2" in one dictionary (sum) and add 1 to the other (count for average calculation). Using `dict.get()` with a default value or `collections.defaultdict` may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sum code.  I will leave it to you to do the average code.

```
for item in my_dict:
    for thing in item['var1']:
        if thing not in results:
            results[thing] = 0
        results[thing] = results[thing] + item['var2']
```

results  {'a': 46, 'b': 84, 'c': 19, 'd': 48, 'e': 56}